# Trying to transfer local files to web server

Tags: ssh, sftp, web-hosting, lamp, digital-ocean

I recently set up Lamp stack on ubuntu 14.04 for my web server. I'm working through Digital Ocean. These are the steps I went through...

On local machine I logged in to my web server with

```
sftp user@web_server_ip
```

Then

```
sftp> cd /var/www/html
```

How would I go upon getting onto my local machine to get the file for the site? And how would I transfer them?

I know that I have to use the [get] and [put] commands

I'm just confused what's considered local/remote? if I'm logged into the remote server on my local machine. Overthinking it?

This is the tutorial I'm trying to follow: [How To Use SFTP to Securely Transfer Files with a Remote Server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-securely-transfer-files-with-a-remote-server)

## Edit:

So I tried moving a whole directory from my local machine and this is what I ended up doing

```
 scp -r /path/directory_name name@ip_address:/var/www/html

 scp: /var/www/html/portfolio.take7: Permission denied
```

Should I be changing permission by using sudo prior to scp -r?

## Edit2:

I have also tried

```
Where_directory_is$ scp -r /path/directory_name name@ip_address:/var/www/html

/var/www/html: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Local is 'your' machine, Remote is the server. You have navigated to where you want the files on the remote. So you need to just do - put <path to file you want to upload on your local machine>

Comment: I navigated to the location where I want to transfer files. How would I go upon getting the file thats on my local machine  to my remove web server ?

Comment: put thefileIwanttotransfer.html

Comment: I'm getting /path/filename.css : no such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

It might be easier to start with [SCP](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/scp.1.html) which allows you to copy files with one command. So for example, if you had a local file /path/filename.css and wanted to transfer it to your server, you could use the following command on your local machine:

```
scp /path/filename.css username@remote_hostname_or_IP:~
```

This command copies the local file and transfers it to the home directory of the username on the remote server using SSH.  You can then SSH in (`ssh username@remote_hostname_or_IP`) and then do what you need with the file sitting in your home directory, such as move it to the proper Apache directory.

Once you start to get more comfortable, you can switch to sftp if you like.

**Update**

Here is how to set up your Apache permissions.  Let's say you have an account `you` on the linux computer running Apache, and we'll say the IP is 192.168.1.100.

On your local machine, create this shell script, `secure.sh`, and remember shell scripts need to have execute privileges (`chmod +x secure.sh`). Fill it with the following contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Lockdown the public web files
find /var/www -exec chown you:www-data {} \;
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod -v 750 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod -v 640 {} \;
```

This shell script is setting the permissions for anything in the `/var/www/` directory to be `750` for the directories and `640` for the files.  This gives `you` complete read/write permissions for the files and `www-data` (which is the account for Apache) read permissions.  Run this anytime you have uploaded files to ensure the permissions are always set correctly.

Next, SSH into your remote computer and go to the `/var/www/html` directory. Ensure that the ownership is not set to root.  If it is, scp the secure.sh file into your remote computer, become root and run it.  This only needs to be done once, so you can remotely set the permissions.

Now you can copy directly to `/var/www/` through the `scp -r` command on your local computer from the top of the directory you wish to copy to `/var/www/html`:

```
scp -r ./ you@192.168.1.100:/var/www/html/
```

Then run this command to remotely run the secure.sh shell script and send the output to out.txt:

```
ssh you@192.168.1.100 -p 23815 ./secure.sh > out.txt
```

Then `cat out.txt` to see that the file permissions changed accordingly.

If this is a public facing computer, then  **you must add an SSH key** to your scp connection. You can use [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2) to find out more about generating your own keys, it is quite easy. To use the key, you only need to add `-i private_key_file` to your `scp` and `ssh` commands.  Lastly, it would actually be safer to keep the /var/www files as root, SSH into the computer, su to become root, then run secure.sh as root (with the owner changed to root in the shell script). It all depends on the level of security you need to worry about. If it is a development computer (which is what I am assuming) no worries then.

Comment: I would be using scp for a single file for example the .css  and .html files. but what would I use to transfer whole directory for example the folder which carries the images needed for the site?

Comment: [answer for previous comment] scp -r will be used for whole directories

Answer (score 0):

For folders use

scp -r root@yourIp:/home/path/ /pathOfDirectory/

For files
scp -r root@yourIp:/home/path/ /pathOfDirectory/file fileNameCopied